# Xstream : with Child element

Tags: xml, xstream

I would like to serialize an object to an XML with Child Element with XStream.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

That's standard functionality.  See the tutorial on Xstream website : http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html